# How do I parse "Nov 20, 2016 12:00:00 AM" to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I found very interesting bug or something like that.

I use this date format `MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a` and it will prints date like this

```
Aug 13, 2020 01:19:50 pm
```

But, when I parse `Nov 20, 2016 12:00:00 AM` to `LocalDateTime`, it throws the exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Nov 20, 2016 12:00:00 AM' could not be parsed at index 22.
```

After I change 'AM' to 'am' it works perfectly!
so `LocalDateTime` literally cannot parse date because of uppercase a̶p̶e̶s̶ letters?
And how can I solve this problem, without replacing 'AM' to 'am' and 'PM' to 'pm'

EDIT

`SimpleDateTime` format doesn't have this problem, he ignores the a̶p̶e̶s̶ letters register (i mean uppercase or lowercase) And I would not like to convert `Date` to `LocalDateTime`

EDIT 2

`MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss A` replace 'a' to 'A' also didn't work

Comment: ahaha, so sorry, it kind of funny, i thought 'apes' translated as 'letter', now i knew it translates like monkey, so stupid misunderstanding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse it in a case-insensitive way. Also, make sure to use an English locale (e.g. `Locale.ENGLISH`, `Locale.US` etc.) because the names of elements are represented with localized strings in the corresponding locales.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time string
        String strDateTime = "Nov 20, 2016 12:00:00 AM";

        // Define the formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                        .appendPattern("MMM d, u h:m:s a")                                       
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);                                     

        // Parse the given date-time into LocalDateTime using formatter
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter);

        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-11-20T00:00
```